# UseEffect with setTimeout runing a Component

Tags: javascript

I try to pass a Component inside of UseEffect and down to setTimout to run only once on my welcome page and i dont get any error it just dosnt run it on my On Mount of the component.

```js
const [intro, setIntro] = useState({ Welcome }); //Welcome is the Component whic should run and pass after 3 seconds ,it is imported as Welcome

useEffect(() => {
    const int = setTimeout(() => {
      return { intro };
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearTimeout(int);
  }, []);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pass a component" and "doesn't run it"?  What exactly are you expecting `return { intro }` to do in a `setTimeout` and why?  Putting *a component* in state is also... highly irregular.  It's really not clear what the goal is with this code.

Comment: You can not render a component within a useEffect. What you can do is set a variable to true in the useEffect, and then check that variable (within the code you actually do render) to see if `intro` should be included in the rendering or not.

Answer (score 2):

Your `return` is from the `setTimeout` callback. That return is completely ignored. To trigger a re-render, you need to set state.

Since you seem to be hardcoding the component, I'd just use a flag (but keep reading):

```
const [showIntro, setShowIntro] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    const int = setTimeout(() => {
        setState(true);
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearTimeout(int);
}, []);

// ...

return (
    <whatever>
    {showIntro && <Welcome />}
    </whatever>
);
```

But if you really want to have the component to show as a state member (which is really unusual):

```
const [intro, setIntro] = useState({ component: Welcome }); // Welcome is the Component which should run and pass after 3 seconds ,it is imported as Welcome
const [introToRender, setIntroToRender] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    const int = setTimeout(() => {
        setIntroToRender(intro);
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearTimeout(int);
}, []);

// ...

return (
    <whatever>
    {introToRender?.component}
    </whatever>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to hide/show a component would be with the use of an boolean state.

```
const [showIntro, setShowIntro] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  const timeoutID = setTimeout(() => setShowIntro(true), 3000);
  return () => clearTimeout(timeoutID);
}, []);

return (
  <>
    {showIntro && <Welcome />}
  </>
);
```

---

To use a component in a state things get a bit more complicated. Since [`useState()` uses any function passed to it for lazy initialisation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state), we can't just pass the `Welcome` component (amusing it is a function component). Instead we have to wrap it inside an object.

```js
const [{ Intro }, setIntro] = useState({ Intro: Noop });
```

[Note that the capital letter `I` within `Intro` is important.](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized) Without it we won't be able to render the component using `<Intro />`.

`Noop` is a function component defined as `() => null`. It does absolutely nothing, with the exception of being a valid function component which can be used with the JSX `<Noop />` syntax.

We can then use `useEffect` to update `Intro` into your `Welcome` component.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const timeoutID = setTimeout(() => setIntro({ Intro: Welcome }));
  return () => clearTimeout(timeoutID);
}, []);
```

Within your return you can then simply use:

```
return (
  <>
    <Intro title="yo" />
  </>
);
```

When you pass attributes like `title` above, they will also be passed to `Noop`, but since `Noop` does nothing the properties will be ignored. They will only be used when `Intro` is set to `Welcome`.

---

Here is a snippet of both solution in action:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function Noop() {
  return null;
}

function Welcome({ title }) {
  return (
    <h1>Welcome {title}</h1>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [showIntro, setShowIntro] = useState(false);
  const [{ Intro }, setIntro] = useState({ Intro: Noop });
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
      setShowIntro(true);
      setIntro({ Intro: Welcome });
    }, 3000);
    
    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {showIntro && <Welcome title="foo" />}
      <Intro title="bar" />
      content...
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```